# Problem with online registration after moving to new URL

Tags: civievent, wordpress

I recently replaced my multisite Wordpress site with a new one that I built on a subdomain. The new one is a simple, one domain site. Everything is working properly, including the Civicrm that I was using with my old site except for the online registration for CiviEvent.

When someone clicks on a link to register for an event, instead of going to the register page:
http://newsite/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/register&reset=1&id=numberofevent

it defaults to the info page:
http://newsite/?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm/event/info&reset=1&id=numberofevent

and gives this error message:
*Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment. 
You do not have permission to access this page*

Hint: when I go into the Wordpress admin area of the site on a specific browser, I can get the links to take me to the registration page without a problem.

Two more points:
When it defaults to the info page with error message, the "/" turns to "%2F"

Also, the same problem occurs for profiles. when I use the "Profile Create Mode" to view the profile, it works on the browser where I am logged in, but on a browser where I am not logged in, I get an error message:

Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
*The requested Profile (gid=numberofprofile) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance.*

Answer (score 1):

Can you make sure that anonymous users have been given the permission to register for events and create/edit profiles.

On install, CiviCRM creates an anonymous user role if one currently does not exist. Ensure you have this role in your WP permissions page.

Comment: I have been looking into the "anonymous user" issue but when I went into the wordpress access control area, there was no column for anonymous users.

Comment: As this is not exactly an answer, I'll just post this as an update to the problem.

Comment: Since I could not figure out the answer, I first upgraded my Civicrm which did not work. Then we installed a new version of Civicrm, plus tested out all the plugins and theme. Finally, after removing a few non essential plugins, it began to work again. It is unclear what combination of actions actually caused it to start functioning normally so its hard to say what the problem and answer actually were.

Comment: i tweaked my answer from your comments. Seems like the issue was the "anonymous user" role not existing

Comment: Thanks Donald. Yes, it was not existing. However, if CiviCRM creates this anonymous user role, its unclear how it did not create the role during install because it definitely was not there.

Answer (score 1):

I forced the creation of the anonymous user role (and granted permissions to the other roles) by adding this at the bottom of civicrm.php:

```
$this->users->set_wp_user_capabilities();
```

I then removed it after reloading a CRM admin page, and found the role created and all the permissions correctly set.
This obviously builds off of Lobo's answer.